# php script not terminate

Tags: php, apache

I have a web server running apache and PHP 5.3.
It works perfectly except that some php scripts don't terminate.
When I run ps aux, there are scripts that started a few days ago.
The max_execution_time is set to 30 seconds (default one).

The problem appeared when my client used the Safari browser - it didn't load the page and the script on the server just stopped executing. Tried Safari on Windows and experienced the same once or twice.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Andrei

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the scripts that are showing up in `ps aux` and not the actual `PHP` process? The actual `PHP` process will run for much longer than the scripts themselves.

Comment: The problem is not the code itself. It happens even in the following code:
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: /login.php');

Comment: When I run ps aux, the script start time is Jul02, Jul03 etc

Comment: Have found that the PHP script ignore the max_execution_time.
I printed the value of the above variable :
echo 'Max execution time: ', ini_get('max_execution_time'), '<br />';
The result is 30. Which means 30 seconds, however I wrote a script with an infinite loop and it run for 2 hours and didn't terminate. Any ideas?